# Ruby on Rails: Do not use database for specific environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, environment-variables

How can I disable the use of a database within a specific environment. I want an environment to purely serve images which does not require a database. A different environment will do the file uploading and management.

The reason why I'm doing it this way is because I want to server the images from images.example.com/image.jpg and manage them from admin.example.com.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this outside rails app via web server. You can create another `server` configuration if you use nginx or `VirtualHost` for apache. 
Example config for nginx:

```
server {
  server_name images.example.com;
  root /path_to_images_directory;
  location / {
    rewrite ^/([^\/]+\.css)$ /css/$1 break;
    rewrite ^/([^\/]+\.js)$ /js/$1 break;
    rewrite ^/([^\/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg))$ /images/$1 break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I currently have Passenger installed, which is why I'm using two virtual hosts configured with two environments pointing at the same document root. But because one environment is different, I get ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished because I have not setup a database in database.yml.

Comment: You don't need passenger for that. For example, if you store images into `public/uploads/images` directory, just point `DocumentRoot` directly to this directory. So all images would be send directly via web server.

Comment: Thats  very simple solution, how did I not see that.

Comment: But, for uploading images, you need to have second `VirtualHost` with passenger :)